# addToJavaScriptWindowObject object isolation

Tags: qt, qwebview

How to make objects, added by QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject inaccessible from "untrusted" scripts?
For example, adding object:

```
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("jtestobj", obj);
```

and **window.jtestobj** must be available only from script **http://example.org/trusted_script.js**, for all others scripts **window.jtestobj** must return **undefined**

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Qt is not possible.

In my opinion there is only one way, using javascript:

In "trusted_script.js", copy your object to new "variable"

```
(function () {
    var objectCopy = window.jtestobj;
    ...
});
```

After delete your object:

```
(function () {
    var objectCopy = window.jtestobj;
    delete window.jtestobj;
});
```

Or set `undefined` (or `null`) in your object:

```
(function () {
    var objectCopy = window.jtestobj;
    window.jtestobj = undefined;//window.jtestobj = null;
});
```